# Let me set inbox message status to unread without having to click on the message

Tags: feature-request, android-app, global-inbox

In the android app I sometimes receive inbox messages that I have already seen on the web interface. However, the only way that I seem to be able to set their status to be unread is to click on them.

Better: menu option to "Mark all as read"

Best: way to mark individual message as read (swipe to the right?)

Comment: IIRC, simply loading/refreshing the inbox will mark them as read (or are you referring to something else?)

Comment: I can confirm it @Shog9. If I get an inbox message, I get a notification in the app. If I read it from the web, the notification is removed automatically.

Comment: @Shog9 that did it. I just didn't know about it. However, I am not sure if that is what I would expect a refresh to do - I would think that refresh would look for new items, but maintain the read/unread status of existing items (what if I had 10 unread items there that I was going through one by one, deliberately leaving them unread until I got to them, and then I "accidentally" refreshed the list, setting all to read-status). I would expect "mark all as read" to be a more explicit, opt-in function.

Comment: Heh, I did that just this morning when trying to read my inbox before coffee. Of course, that can be a problem with the web interface as well (note the top of the Related list).

Comment: Voted to close as dupe of newer, better worded, request.